# Problems with Solidfy Modifier for 3D Printing; creating a gap

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing

I'm having an issue with the solidify modifier. First off, all of my bodies are manifold so I've already been through that drill. However, every time I use the solidify modifier it adds thickness to the model but it doesn't "fill-in" the model. It seems to leave a void gap between the outer layer and the inner layer (see attached images). Can someone explain to me how I create a model that is "filled-in" and why it does this? Trying to 3D print an alien.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you forgot to upload the images…

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding on how the solidify modifier works. It basically takes your model, scales it in, and reverses the normals. So you would model the outside of a glass, and then the solidify modifier generates the inside. It doesn't fill it in with some sort of actual material, it just creates another surface to make it look solid. From my understanding, A piece of software for converting a 3D models into something that can be printed will make things solid. So if we where to go back to the cup example, the software would make the parts of the cup that were solidified solid.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. So as long as the model is manifold the pre-printer editing software should fill in the bodies?

Comment: I added the image as an attachment to my original message but I'm not sure where it went...

Comment: @catlover2 how do I upload an image in the comments? I'm new to the forum. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can edit your question and add an image to the question. Remember to actually post it - a preview gets generated as you edit, but it's not visible to anyone else until you post it.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you really want to post an image in a comment, you can use the answer box below to upload an image but then post the URL in a comment.

Comment: Have you tried remesh modifier? This might be able to do what you are looking for